# ng new hello Error: Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist. Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist

Tags: angular

I am facing problem in creating new project in angular.
When I run ng new myapp command I get following command

`ng new hello`

```
Error: Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.
Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.
```

can anyone help me out???

Comment: did any answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Solution

```
Please make sure that your new folder have write permission
```

if you are using ubuntu please run the command below to that folder

```
sudo chmod 644 -R foldername
```

then run ng new appname

and check your node version too

Comment: there are a angular-cli version that gives this error. Try reinstall angular-cli: npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest or install a old version: npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@1.5.3

Comment: @Rahul VV , after following above steps still i am facing same issue. cli version: 1.4.9, node: 9.3.0, OS: linux x64 (Ubuntu 16)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by simply deleting all node_module folders on my disk:

- Open Finder (on Mac) or Explorer (on Windows)
- search for all occurrences of node_module folders
- move all of these to the trash bin (you can undo this, but should not need to).

And that's it. Seems like there was clutter lying around.

Please keep in mind, this is the wooden hammer method. 
Your projects need to be rebuilt from scratch after this.

Answer (score 1):

It means the folder in which you are creating angular project is corrupted. The same command will work in some other Path.

Answer (score 0):

My explanation for this "black magic" of corrupted folder as @prathiba palanisami mentioned is that you may have node-modules "corrupted" from older install in your own folder.