# Error while creating angular app through cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, typescript2.0

ng new my-new-ap 
Error: Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist. 
Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.

**ng-version:** 
Angular CLI: 1.7.4 
Node: 8.11.1 
OS: darwin x64

Comment: Deplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765941/ng-new-hello-error-path-app-app-module-ts-does-not-exist-path-app-app-mod

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng new hello Error: Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist. Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765941/ng-new-hello-error-path-app-app-module-ts-does-not-exist-path-app-app-mod)